# Which Method would be the best to predict the outcome with 6 possibilites?

Tags: r, classification, prediction

i would like to predict the "Ranking" (1-6) of one of my 6 coffeemachines with the Big Five personality traits (OCEAN) and i don't really know which Algorythms would be the best for this task. Any recommendation would be a great help for me.
I have tried to predict it with C5.0 but the result was pretty bad so i thought maybe there is a better way or method to predict it. Or maybe i am doing something wrong because i am pretty new to machine learning and prediction.

My table looks like this: (116 entries)
[image]

All "BFI_" columns are numeric and have a range from 1-5.
The "Philips" column (Ranking for Philips coffee machine) is of datatype factor (1-6).
    .

```
ind <- sample(2, nrow(dfrandomzied), replace = T, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)) 
set.seed(100)    
train <- df[ind == 1,]

test <- df[ind == 2,]

# Building the model
m1 <- C5.0(train[,1:5], train$Philips) 
summary(m1)

# Prediction with Testdaten
p1 <- predict(m1, test)
```

## Summary of m1

[image]

## Prediction p1 results

```
# Prediction with Testdaten
p1 <- predict(m1, test)

# Auswertung Confusionmatrix
confusionMatrix(p1, test$Philips)
```

[image]

Any advice is welcome :). Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Simply copy-paste. Please edit to remove all images from the question.

Comment: You seem to be asking for recommendations for statistical methods or interpretations of results from statistical methods. These are not specific programming questions that are appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need statistical advice, the website for that help is [stats.se]